# SSRS Total count error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have a weird problem with SSRS and have studied countless Post/material for this unique problem with SSRS.

Need some clarification.

I have a matrix to calculate the total of employees who has done survey in dataset. In my database, for every question marked yes and no or likert scale question from (1 to4 values) so for each Question `Qxx_A_1` ,we have `N_Qxx_A_1` columns.

i.e As per the attachment, I am calculating the total of all the employees whose did the survey but if its value is less than 5, i need to hide it with "*" (to maintain privacy) . Even if the "*" has value like 1,2,3,4 so i need this value in total but it doesn't work.

For some condition this statement works well but for some condition it doesn't work well.

```
=IIF(IsNumeric(ReportItems!textbox4.Value) = 0, "*", Count(Fields!N_Q3_A_1.Value))
```

Can someone help me in writing custom code.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using 0 instead of "*" in your formulas.
then just go into text box properties and set to display * instead of 0.

[image]

Comment: tried that, but it doesn't worked as well

Updated formulas

=IiF(IsNumeric(ReportItems!Textbox28.Value) = 0,0, Count(Fields!N_Q36.Value))